# weigh vs. weighs in 'Together the chain and necklace weigh(s) 5 grams.'

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Does anyone know which of these 2 sentences uses ***weigh*** vs. ***weighs*** correctly.

1. Together the chain and necklace ***weigh*** 5 grams.
2. Together the chain and necklace ***weighs*** 5 grams.

In sentence 1. (in my brain) the chain and necklace can be replaced by Together ***they*** weigh.

In sentence 2. (in my brain) the chain and necklace can be replaced by Together ***it*** weighs.

I'm not sure which sentence 1. or 2. is grammatically correct.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Probably both are considered grammatically correct, for the reasons you give. It's not always one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

If the chain and necklace are two separate things, it makes much more sense to refer to them with the plural ***they***, and therefore the more fluent-sounding sentence is "(they) **weigh** five grams."  It doesn't sound correct to refer to two separate objects as *it*.

The only time I can think of when we might refer to multiple items with a singular verb is when they are considered inseparable, like one item.  For example, you might say "A ball and chain *is* tattooed on his chest."

Comment: Thanks stangdon!  In this case I actually have a necklace with a pendant on the necklace.  So, would the correct method still be to say, 'Together the necklace and pendant weigh five grams.'

Comment: Yes, it sounds more correct to me to say "weigh".